# Entity Framework - Remove List of Items

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to delete a list of items from a database with entity framework, however I can't get the sub lists not to load,

essentially I have a list for which each item of that list contains a 2 list, I want to not load the sub lists but just the list it self.

How do I only load the list and not its sub lists?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the sub lists are being LazyLoaded when they are evaluated.  You can turn Lazy Loading off with

```
DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).  I typically turn LazyLoading off in the constructor of my context and eager load anything I need with include statements.  Lazy Loading can also cause performance issues.  If you loop through a lazy loading collection you'll end up with one database hit per item in the collection.

Comment: Tried adding it to here but didn't appear to solve the lists not loading public DbContext()
            : base("name=DbContext")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint there and verify that it's using that constructor.  Also can you post the query.

Comment: It does hit the break point and that appears to work now, I think I may have not reloaded it or something. However I am still getting the following error.       
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.'

Comment: That seems to imply that you have another entity referencing the one you are trying to delete in a 1 to 1 relationship (and not a 1 to 0..1 relationship) you wont be able to delete this entity.  You could try adding a nullable key using the convention public int? SomeEntityId {get;set;} next to your public SomeEntity SomeEntity {get;set;} and it should switch it to a 1 to 0..1.  It may also have something to do with the collections, but unless you've removed one of the Cascade Delete Conventions I'd expect those to take care of themselves.